# MacOSX: Distribution for beta distribution in itunesConnect

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect, testflight

Need to distribute a beta version of my MacOSX app using the appStore (itunes Connect) in the same way I do with the iOS apps. But when upload the build to the itunes connect I don't have the option either to select testers or to send it the app to test

[image]

Aa you can see I only have the option to see the build of my app in comparison with the iOS:

[image]

Here is the details of testflight in the app:

[image]

Any of you knows what can I be doing wrong or missing ?